# Minimum spanning trees of sub-graphs?

Tags: algorithm, graph, tree, minimum-spanning-tree, spanning-tree

**Any hint please if I should prove or search for counterexample, at least to know which direction to go...**

Consider the following 2 graphs:

```
G1 (V, E1)
G2 (V, E2)
```

and a weight function for the vertices `w: (E1 \untion E2) -> R`

and 2 minimum spanning trees `T1, T2` of `G1` and `G1`.

We define a new graph: `G(V, E1 \untion E2)`

Is it true to say that there is always a minimum spanning tree `T` in the new graph `G` (using same `w` function) such that **all** edges of T are from `T1` or `T2`?

---

The claim is wrong in case for every T it has an edge e which isn't included in T1 or T2, Now in G1 we can remove this edge (e) and the problem is solved for T1. But I can't remove edge e from G2 too, which means I must take it and the claim is right, am I wrong?

Note: no need for detailed answer, only looking to know what is correct and giving it myself a deep prove and thinking.

Comment: Hint: compare what Kruskal's algorithm would do on (V, E1 U E2) versus (V, T1 U T2).

Comment: @DavidEisenstat can you kindly read the updated question, on why I think it's true. plus you just wrote  (V, T1 U T2) T1 and T2 are not edges.

Comment: I don't follow your proof. "The claim is wrong in case T has an edge e which isn't included in T1 or T2." No, the claim is wrong if for *all* MSTs T, there exists such an edge. The rest I don't understand.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat you are right, just can you guide me which direction to go? (if it's true to not) so I would spend time on proving or finding contradiction example (probably I think it's true)

Comment: Why don't you work some small examples by hand? I think you'll either find a counterexample or get a good feel for how the proof should go.

Comment: I tried many and non worked as counterexample, so probably it's true but I don't "feel" that way eaither

Comment: @DavidEisenstat any hint please?

Comment: Why would Kruskal's algorithm choose an edge in (E1 U E2) \ (T1 U T2)?